Why does applying map to a dataset in tensorflow return empty values?
I am working with 12 band images, the images are in tiff format so I have to apply to the dataset a map to read them in that format and stack them in a size of (132,132,12).
the problem is that when I apply the map I get back a matrix of (132,132,12) but with empty values 0, however if I apply the same method without the map I get the correct values.
# Read all images tif paths
all_imgs = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_train, '*/*/*/*.tif'))

labels = list(map(lambda x: x.split('/')[-4], all_imgs))
labels = np.array(labels)[::12]
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)

# Reshape all images
all_imgs = np.array(all_imgs).reshape(2528,12)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((all_imgs, labels))

up to this point my dataset is defined, which contains for each observation 12 image paths corresponding to each band and its respective class.
def images_process(ds, crop):
    idx = 0
    tensors = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=channels)

    for i in ds:
        img = tf.io.read_file(i)
        img = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(img)
        img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
        img = tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])[:,:,1]
        tensors.write(idx, img)
        idx+=1
        
    return tf.reshape(tensors.stack(), (img_height,img_width, channels)), crop

this is the function with which I map the dataset
for i in ds.map(images_process).as_numpy_iterator():
    print(i[0][0])
    break

So when I run the above code to see a little of what comes back I find the following:
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

However when running the same code with a small test case the output is completely different:
idx = 0
tensors = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=channels)

for i in all_imgs[0]:
    img = tf.io.read_file(i)
    img = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(img)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])[:,:,0]
    tensors.write(idx, img)
    idx+=1

print(tensors.stack()[0])

Output:
tf.Tensor(
[[0.01960784 0.01960784 0.01960784 ... 0.05882353 0.05490196 0.05490196]
 [0.01960784 0.01960784 0.01960784 ... 0.05490196 0.05490196 0.05490196]
 [0.01568628 0.01960784 0.01960784 ... 0.0509804  0.05490196 0.05882353]
 ...
 [0.05882353 0.0509804  0.04705883 ... 0.03137255 0.04313726 0.03921569]
 [0.05882353 0.0509804  0.04705883 ... 0.04313726 0.04313726 0.04313726]
 [0.05490196 0.04705883 0.0509804  ... 0.03921569 0.04313726 0.0509804 ]], shape=(132, 132), dtype=float32)

I have tried several ways, using lists, with numpy and nothing has worked, I have received inaccessibility errors, I have also investigated about the SymbolicTensors that seems to be the problem but I have not been able to solve it either, I also tried to add the decorator 'tf.function' but again the same result.
i would like to know how to solve it using or without using map
thank you very much in advance
